# How to Find busiest Geographies by Location - cumulative sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to locate the busiest consumer geographies for each location, but then return just enough geographies per location so that I get at least 90% of the consumers for each location. Database is postgres.

DB fiddle with data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uUgChHGoF33khmXZPRxTkR/2

Within these data are 7 locations with their busiest geographies and the percent of total that each loc-geo represents.
Data Sample (ex, geo 609 represents 75.7% of Location A's business):

```
    Location    Geo     loc_geo_pct_total
    A           609     0.757
    A           479     0.193
    A           463     0.006
    A           606     0.003
    ...
    D           609     0.903
    D           604     0.060
    ...and so on
```

I thought I would start by trying to get the cumulative sum per location when sorting by geo% descending, making an output appear like this:

```
    Location    Geo     loc_geo_pct_total   cumul_loc_geo
    A           609     0.757               0.757
    A           479     0.193               0.950
    A           463     0.006               0.956
    A           606     0.003               0.959
    ...
    D           609     0.903               0.903
    D           604     0.060               0.963
    ...and so on
```

I've tried different queries, including this one, but this query is wrong because it keeps accumulating regardless of location.

```
    select location, geo, 
    sum(pctoftotal) over (order by location, geo desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as loc_geo_cumul_pct
    from tdata
    order by 1, 3 desc;
```

How do I modify this query and return results like the shape above?

Once I figure that out, then I can move onto the second problem, where I only want to show enough geographies per location to get to >= 90%. So, my data would ultimately show 2 geographies per location, except location D only needs one geography because geo 609 exceeds 0.9.

Any help on the first issue would be appreciated, and then I can take on the 2nd issue.

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong link before here is the new. Does this work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uUgChHGoF33khmXZPRxTkR/3

Comment: Yes, thanks Jorge. I think I'm good now with issue one.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uUgChHGoF33khmXZPRxTkR/5

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks, your version also works for issue 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `partition by:`

```
select location, geo, 
    sum(pctoftotal) over (partition by location order by geo desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as loc_geo_cumul_pct
    from tdata
```

Edit 1:

```
select location, geo, 
        sum(pctoftotal) over (partition by location order by loc_geo_pct_total desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as loc_geo_cumul_pct
        from tdata
```

Edit 2:

```
--selecting only rows where loc_geo_cumul_pct<=start_loc_geo`
Select * from
(
--find first value for each location where loc_geo_cumul_pct>=0.9
Select *,min(case when loc_geo_cumul_pct>=0.9 then loc_geo_cumul_pct end) over (partition by location) start_loc_geo
from
 (
   select location, geo, 
            sum(pctoftotal) over (partition by location order by loc_geo_pct_total desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as loc_geo_cumul_pct
            from tdata
 ) X
) Y 
Where loc_geo_cumul_pct<=start_loc_geo
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's giving me inaccurate results, showing the wrong geos for each location.

Comment: Try to use instead of  statement order by geo desc - order by loc_geo_pct_total desc

Comment: Ok, thanks, that worked. I think I tried that before but dismissed because I made a mistake in ordering the data after the fact. Will accept this answer, thanks! Any suggestions for the 2nd issue? I admit that I haven't tried issue 2 yet, but will give it some effort.

Comment: @Isolated . . . How does this answer the 90% question?

Comment: Isolated, you are welcome)). I add some edit 2 for your 2 issue)

Comment: @GordonLinoff The most recent update by Olga addresses issue 2.

Comment: Isolated, Thanks for feedback)